# Для каждого td свой клас

Tags: asp.net

Нужно чтоб в выводе каждой таблицы был свой класс.

Есть таблица, и при нажатии на кнопку ключ, нужно чтоб выводилась строка под ней.

Ну так как у всех строк 1 класс, то выводит все.

```
             TableRow trow1 = new TableRow();
                TableCell tcell1 = new TableCell();
                TableCell tcell2 = new TableCell();
                TableCell tcell3 = new TableCell();
                output_table.Rows.Add(trow1);
                tcell1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a href='"+result.GetString(2)+"'>"+ result.GetString(0) + "</a>"));
                trow1.Cells.Add(tcell1);
                tcell1.CssClass="tbI0";
                tcell2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a href='" + result.GetString(2) + "'>Загрузить</a>"));
                trow1.Cells.Add(tcell2);
                tcell2.CssClass="tbI2";
                tcell3.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a href='#'>Ключ</a>"));
                trow1.Cells.Add(tcell3);

                TableRow trow2 = new TableRow();
                TableCell tcellkey = new TableCell();
                tcellkey.ColumnSpan = 3;
                tcellkey.CssClass="keylic";
                trow2.Cells.Add(tcellkey);
                tcellkey.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(result.GetString(1)));
                output_table.Rows.Add(trow2);
```

Нужно чтоб td был скрытый, и при нажатии на "Ключ" выводился только тот который присвоен к строке.

Comment: На `javascript` не пойдет? Или на `php`?

Comment: нет, нужно на asp